# Using two past forms in one sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use two past forms in one sentence.
For example:

> I got owned.

or

> She got carried by her friend to her house.

"Got","owned" and ""carried" are past forms.

Comment: *get* is often used in these cases, in a slang way as said in the answer below. Your second sentence can be rephrased as *she had herself carried by her friend to her house.* This uses the structure *have + object + past participle.*

Comment: "Owned" is not here a past tense, but a "past participle". I put that in quotes because it does not necessarily have a past meaning - with parts of _be_ or (informally) _get_ it is passive, in whatever tense the preceding verb is.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking *past* forms with *past participle* forms, which are here used in a *passive voice* context.

Remember when you learned your irregular verbs ? Get/got/got, sink/sank/sunk, etc. The second column is the *past form*, while the third is the *past participle* form.

**Past participles** are used:

- After an auxiliary, to form the present perfect or the past perfect.

  > I **have been** to New York this summer.
- After a stative verb to use the passive form.

  > The car **was repaired** by Paul.

In your example, it is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically incorrect, but common slang.  Especially "got owned".

The correct way to say the second would be:

> She was carried by her friend to her house.

Comment: It is in no wise grammatically incorrect. It is however informal.

Comment: @ColinFine Good to know. I thought the use of *get* as a passive auxiliary was grammatically incorrect.